# Vue router Auth-guard function doesn't check Vuex store state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I am trying to set-up an auth-guard for a profile page. I am using Vue (2.0) with vue-router and Vuex for state. My backend is firebase, but I don't think that's imporant here? My auth-guard function seems unable to properly fetch the requiresAuth state.

This is my auth-guard function:

```
  {
path: "/profile",
name: "Profile",
component: Profile,
meta: {
  requiresAuth: true
}


}
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {  
  console.log('-----------ROUTE GUARD PROPS--------');
  console.log(store.state.user.isAuthorized);
  console.log(store.state.user);
  console.log('----------- END ROUTE GUARD PROPS--------');
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    if (store.state.user.isAuthorized) {
      next()
    } else {
      next("/Login")
    }
  } else {
      next()
  }
})
```

And the result in the browser console when changing pages is the following:
[image: Browser Console]

The issue here, to be clear, is why the `console.log` contradicts the `isAuthorized` in the print-out of the `user` module's `state`. For reference, my store has a `user` and `shared` module. The `user` module has a `state` with two members: `user` and `isAuthorized`. Hence the browser output.

Any ideas why these two conflict?

Comment: So you're asking why `console.log(store.state.user.isAuthorized)` and `console.log(store.state.user)` shows two different things in the console?

Comment: Well, why `console.log(store.state.user.isAuthorized)` appears to be `false` but the `isAuthorized` within the `store.state.user` is `true`. I feel like these should be the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because when you expand an object in the console, it will evaluate the object and its values based on the time of expanding, and not based on the time of logging it. It should tell you when the value was evaluated, if you hover the small blue square with an `!` in it.
[image]

Meaning that, when you log the object. `isAuthorized` is indeed `false`, as you can see when you log the property directly, but when you go and expand the object in the console it's `true`. Because at some point after logging it, some part of your program has changed ´isAuthorized´ to `true`.

The display also varies a little whether your console is open at the time of logging the value of not.
The below screenshots are based on the snippet at the end of this post, so you can try it yourself.

The first image is how it looks if the console is closed at the time of logging. Here it simply shows `Object`, and when you expand it, it shows `state` is `true`.

[image]

In the second picture, the console was open when logging, and here it shows `state: false`, and when you expand it, it shows `state: true`, because it's fetching the current state of the object.

[image]

```js
const object = {
  state: false
}

console.log('State:', object.state)
console.log('Object:', object)

object.state = true
```

```html
Open up your browsers console to see the output.
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer - especially since I was unaware of the promote aspec (I'm new at this). This is indeed the answer to the question, though I really don't understand why the `state` could be false. But, that appears to be a different question than what I asked.

Comment: @Paco My guess would be, that what ever code that authenticates the user, is run after entering the route in question. Good luck :)